# How Can i convert my phonegap app in to a downloadable one?

Tags: android, html, phonegap-build, phonegap

I Made My first App On Phonegap And Tested It By Phonegap Mobile App,Now How Can I Make It In To Apk Or Install To My Mobile Phone?

Comment: https://build.phonegap.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [Adobe build](https://build.phonegap.com) then follow these steps:

1. Upload signing key
2. Set Certificate and alias for the key
3. Build the apk for android using the uploaded signing key
4. Press Install after successful build.

Comment: Not so simple. Android will refuse to install your app unless you enable "Unknown Sources" in Settings > Security.